# Unir Filas en tabla HTML 5

Tags: html

Hola como puedo hacer esto con las tablas HTML:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que he hecho:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowSpan="4">
      date time
    </td>
    <td>.</td>
    <td rowSpan="4">
      description
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>.</td>
    <td rowSpan="2">|</td>
    <td>.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>.</td>
    <td rowSpan="2">|</td>
    <td>.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>.</td>
    <td rowSpan="2">|</td>
    <td>.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: usas algun framework css ?

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent no, pero aunque fuera con framework, como seria?

Comment: usando el grid; normalmente los frameworks CSS tienen un sistema de grid como bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/

Comment: Hacer diseño con tablas es generalmente una mala idea. ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer? Quizás sería mejor usar CSS Grid.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que debes pensar es que colspan y rowspan no van a alterar el órden de pintado de las tablas.
Por ello primero debes definir las columnas, y la primera fila tiene tres.

Eso nos pintará la primera idea que es digamos la parte predecible.

```css
* {
  border: 2px dashed goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowSpan="4" class="bordered">
      a
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowSpan="4" class="bordered">
      c
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Para la segunda parte, sabemos que la columna de en medio ya está completa, por lo que no deberemos de preocuparnos porque se encime en la primera fila.
Como la primera columna de la primera fila tiene un rowspan > 2 entonces la primera celda ya estará cubierta, y el primer elemento de esa segunda fila se pintará en la segunda fila. como el tercer elemento de la segunda fila está ya ocupado por el tercer elemento de la priemra fila el siguiente elemento que agreguemos en la segunda fila se irá automáticamente a la tercera, en el segundo espacio que no está ocupado.

```css
* {
  border: 2px dashed goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowSpan="4" class="bordered">
      a
    </td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td rowSpan="4" class="bordered">
      c
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td class="bordered">b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

uniendo los conceptos anteriores obtendremos:

```css
.bordered {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowSpan="4" class="bordered">
      a
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td rowSpan="4" class="bordered">
      c
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bordered">b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  
 <!-- comienza a repetir -->
 <tr>
    <td rowSpan="4" class="bordered">
      d
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td rowSpan="4" class="bordered">
      f
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bordered">e</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
 <!-- 3 -->
 <tr>
    <td rowSpan="4" class="bordered">
      g
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td rowSpan="4" class="bordered">
      i
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bordered">h</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```